# compare 2 objects and adjust the second one based on first in a smarter way

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have a function with 2 objects .It is supposed to compare the first one with second and modify the second one based on first one.
Remove all objects not present in first object but is present in second object, from second object
Add all objects present in first, but not in second, to second object

I need to do it this way because the ordering present in object2 is important and cannot be touched.

Can I do this in a smarter way, maybe using lodash?

```
        const object1 = nextProps
        var object2 = [...this.state.changes]
        object1.map(source =>
            object2.find(item => source.id === item.id)
            ? null
            : object2.push(source)
        )
        const objectCopy = [...object2]
        objectCopy.map((item, index) => object1.find(source => source.id === item.id)
            ? null
            : object2.splice(index, 1, null))
        object2 = object2.filter(item => item !== null)
        return object2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.intersection()` to keep in `arr2` all items that are also found in `arr1`, and then use `_.difference()` to get all items in `arr1` that don't exist in `arr2`. Combine both using array spread:

**Note**: These are arrays, and not object so `arr1` & `arr2` (instead of `object1` and `object2` respectively)

```
const arr1 = nextProps
const arr2 = this.state.changes

return [
  ..._.intersection(arr2, arr1, 'id'), // preserve all items in arr2 that exist in arr1
  ..._.difference(arr1, arr2, 'id') // add all items that exist in arr1 but are missing from arr2
]
```